# Installing Jenssegers/MongoDB in a Laravel Sail 8.0 environment

Tags: laravel, mongodb, docker, wsl-2, jenssegers-mongodb

So I've managed to do a clean install of Laravel in Windows using WSL2. One of the requirements of my project is to have two databases running at the same time mysql and mongodb.

I added an image of MongoDB in my docker-compose.yml as the dock-hub tells me, but when I try to add the jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package sail tells me I don't have the correct requirements.

**How do I connect both containers properly, so I can install the package without any issues?**

Logs:

```
~/example-app$ sail composer require jenssegers/mongodb:"^3.8"
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update jenssegers/mongodb
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, ..., v3.8.1] require mongodb/mongodb ^1.6 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.6.0, ..., 1.9.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.9.x-dev is an alias of mongodb/mongodb dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - mongodb/mongodb[dev-master, 1.8.0-RC1, ..., v1.8.x-dev] require ext-mongodb ^1.8.1 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
    - mongodb/mongodb[1.6.0, ..., v1.6.x-dev] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mongodb/mongodb[1.7.0-beta1, ..., v1.7.x-dev] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires jenssegers/mongodb ^3.8 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, v3.8.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ldap.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - mongo
            # - selenium

    # ...

    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail

    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 8081:8081
        environment:
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example    
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Comment: I don't know how to set it up in docker, but the error you are having is because of lack of extension `extension=mongodb.so`, what I did in linux is install via pecl, you can figure out how to do that in docker, for reference this is the pecl command`sudo pecl install mongodb`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I manage to install this package :3 First I extract Docker config, by run this command

```
php artisan sail:publish
```

then edit file `docker/8.0/Dockerfile`, add following lines after the `RUN apt-`  one

```yaml
RUN pecl install mongodb

RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
```

save it, then run this command to rebuild docker

```
sail build --no-cache
```

Comment: Why do you use artisan? Where is the documentation?

Comment: Did you just assume that PECL works on PHP 8 ?

Comment: @JuniorUsca here the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sail-customization

Comment: @MotassemMK it works and my project along with my answer is still working, so
yes it works on php 8

Comment: I had to use `>>` in order not to overwrite the php.ini: `RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

@I3lackheart answer is correct: but I needed to change param:

`context: ./docker/8.1`

under
`laravel.tests: \n build:`
because without it docker still reads vendor version of Dockerfile not one in project root/docker folder.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
#Step 1 
#edit vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/[PHP VERSION]/Dockerfile
#Ex: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile

#Step 2 
#Add the command at Dockerfile file
RUN apt-get install -y php8.1-mongodb
  
#Step 3 
#Save it and then run ./vendor/bin/sail build and ./vendor/bin/sail up -d
./vendor/bin/sail build && ./vendor/bin/sail up -d
```

Comment: You should never directly edit the vendor files as they will be removed/overwritten.